# Framework not found Pods_Runner

Tags: flutter, xcode

Estoy tratando de iniciar mi aplicación flutter en ios y me está dando problemas. En android funciona perfectamente, pero en ios cuando voy a compilar xcode 14.3 en mi mac con 16 gb y procesador M1, falla. Recibo los siguientes errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que estás usando `XCode`, debes eliminar:

```
 Pod_Runner.framework
```

ve a <kbd>Build Phases</kbd> > <kbd>Link Binary WIth Libraries</kbd>
elimina:

```
Pod_Runner.framework
```

Esto será suficiente para que funcione `Flutter`

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado perfectamente :D

Comment: Excelente @DanielBorderaCliment me parece que a todos nos sucede este problema haha.